# Where do the limits of integration of this electric field problem come from?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, coulombs-law

> [image: 1]

If we have a uniformly charged ring with negligible thickness, we can say that $$\text{d}E=K_e\frac{\text{d}q}{r^2}$$

Then after resolving $\text{d}E$ into its two components, we find that the horizontal components cancel out due to symmetry so $$\text{d}E_Z=2\text{d}\cos\theta$$
where $\theta$ is the vertex angle. Now, after simplifying a bit by replacing $\cos\theta$ with $z/r$, we have
$$\text{d}E_Z=2K_e\frac{z\text{d}q}{r^3}$$

Now, since $z$, $K_e$ and $r$ are constants, we can integrate
$$E_Z=2\frac{K_e z}{r^3}\int_0^{q_{ring}/2}\text{d}q$$

Where did the limits of integration $0$ and $q_{ring}/2$ come from?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense.  Your  small charge $dq=d (d\theta)$ so you should be integrating around the axis angle $\theta$.  The factor of $2$ is also suspicious.  It could be that the solution uses symmetry to integrate over half the ring and then multiply by $2$ since by symmetry both halves of the ring will contribute equally.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Yes that is the case symmetry is used in this problem , also we avoid double integration that's why I didn't say dq=d(d$\theta$) (because I didn't take it in my math course yet)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Did you mean $dq = \frac{q_{\rm ring}}{2\pi} d\theta$? I don't know what $d(d\theta)$ means.

Comment: a small charge of size $dq$ is contained on an arc of radius $d$ (the radius of your ring) and (infinitesimal) opening angle $d\theta$.   Your notation is why one should never use $d$ for radii in physics.  and you’re right: $q/2\pi d$ would be the linear charge density.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I never understood arguments about $dq$. Instead, theses problems are better understood by using the general formula for the electric field in a 1-dimensional static charge distribution:

$$\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_C\frac{\lambda(\mathbf{r'})(\mathbf{r-r'})}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|^3}d l'$$

where $\lambda$ is your charge distribution (a constant, in this case), $\mathbf{r}$ is your position vector, $\mathbf{r'}$ is a vector that points to your charge distribution, and $C$ is the domain on which the charge density is non-zero.

In your problem, $\mathbf{r}=z\mathbf{\hat z}$ (since you're only interested in the electric field at points on the z-axis) and  $\mathbf{r'}=x'\mathbf{\hat x}+y'\mathbf{\hat y}$ (since the charge distribution lies in the x'y' plane) Additionally,

$$|\mathbf{r-r'}|=\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2}=\sqrt{(x')^2+(y')^2+z^2}=\sqrt{R^2+z^2}$$

where $R$ is the radius of the circle. With all of that:

$$\mathbf{E}=\frac{\lambda}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_C\frac{-x'\mathbf{\hat x}-y'\mathbf{\hat y}+z\mathbf{\hat z}}{\left[R^2+z^2 \right]^{3/2}}dl'$$

Ignoring components in the $\mathbf{\hat x}$ and $\mathbf{\hat y}$ components (symmetry) and converting to cylindrical coordinates, for which $dl'=R d\phi'$

$$\mathbf{E}=\frac{\lambda\mathbf{\hat z}}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_C\frac{z}{\left[R^2+z^2 \right]^{3/2}}dl'=\frac{\lambda\mathbf{\hat z}}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_{\phi'=0}^{2\pi}\frac{z R}{\left[R^2+z^2 \right]^{3/2}} d\phi'$$

Noting that $R$ and $z$ are constant with respect to the variable of integration, the answer becomes

$$\mathbf{E}(z)=\frac{\lambda R z}{2\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{\left(R^2+z^2 \right)^{3/2}}\mathbf{\hat z}$$

since the integral equals $2\pi$.

I know that this may not be what you're looking for, but it's the only way that I understand it. I absolutely do not understand arguments relating to $dq$. They seem to only be used in poorly-written Freshman textbooks because the authors think that they're easier to understand than a basic line integral.

Anyway... If you understand the logic of what I've presented, you can repeat the argument for any charge distribution without ever worrying about the relationship between $\mathbf{E}$ and $dq$, whatever that means.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the factor of “2” (it drops out).  The integral of dq is just “q”, the total charge.