# Why can't we integrate over a charge $Q$?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, integration

I've just started self-studying electricity and magnetism, and I am learning to calculate charge over line/surface/volumes. The standard procedure consists of changing the integrating variable from dq to space, the reason being that "we cannot integrate over a charge".
For example, take this tutorial https://physics.nfshost.com/textbook/06-Integration/01-Introduction.php

> In particular, we don't know what the limits of integration are so we can't come up with a number: generally speaking, we know how to find the limits of integration if we're integrating over space (i.e. $x$) or time ($t$), but not over some other quantity like charge.

I don't get this. Why can't we integrate over a charge? It seems obvious to me that $ \int_0^Q dq = Q$, where $Q$ is the total charge of a rod.
What am I missing?

Comment: Hint : If you think of a uniformly charged conductor then what's the starting point of integral is? $0$? It's equally charged all way around

Answer (score 2):

I actually wrote a long rant about this recently [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/698822/where-do-the-limits-of-integration-of-this-electric-field-problem-come-from/698844#698844). As it turns out, $dq$ is just a placeholder for either $\lambda dl$ in one dimension, $\sigma dA$ is two dimensions, and $\rho dV$ in three dimensions. One advantage is that they have a well-defined form. $dV$ can be found through the Jacobian determinant. Likewise, $dA$ and $dl$ have well-defined forms from the theory of surface integrals and line integrals, respectively.

For really simple cases (where the integrand is constant and your geometry is flat), you can get away with integrating over $dq$. But if your charge distribution is curved or variable over space, then the $dq$ usage breaks down and stops making sense, in my opinion. There is also a problem with the limits of integration: what does it even mean to integrate from $q=0$ to $q=Q$?

In reality, this usage (sometimes) works because you use $q$ to *parameterize* your line/surface/volume integral. But there's no real advantage to this, since $dq$ obfuscates the meaning of your integral (and their integration limits) and you lose the advantage of having well defined differentials.

Personally, I wish that textbook authors would stop using $dq$ in basic E&M. It obfuscates a simple integral for no apparent reason.

Comment: You can imagine it making sense in the context of a charging capacitor. Not that it actually gets used that way.

Comment: That's actually where my frustration comes from! There are a lot of inconsistent and silly ways of using $dq$ here, in the theory of capacitors, and in the theory of current. It's so much easier to think of all of those things as line, surface, or volume integrals.

Comment: I think I got a better explanation and wanted your opinion. The main reason to integrate over time or space is that we want to integrate out time or space. For example, if we want to know the electric field of a rod, we want it around the whole length of the rod (that is, not to be dependent on any particular position along the rod), so we need to compute the integral along it's space $x$ (to "integrate $x$ out"). Indeed, there are examples in which this is not required and integrate over $dq$ makes sense (see here https://www.physics.udel.edu/~watson/phys208/exercises/kevan/efield1.html )